# "The child may not feel as loved", what's the meaning of "as" here?

Tags: grammar

As the question title, what's the meaning of 'as' here? Is the sentence meaning - 'The child may not feel that he is loved'?

Comment: The child may not feel that loved, or loved as much (as he is supposed to be or as much as he  -the child-  may expect or would like to be). There is an unexpressed comparison in the sentence.

Comment: _As loved_ is an implicit comparison, and should appear with an additional _as_ clause to indicate the baseline being compared with. The sentence has had that second clause deleted (probly because it was obvious in the context). So maybe it meant _The child may not feel as loved .._, with a continuing clause like _.. as the child had felt before `X`_, or _.. as the child's older brother._ Et cetera; there are a lot ot things it can mean, but there's not enough information to tell. So we hafta make up a story; humans are good at that.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include additional context? That would help provide a referent for "as" and resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks all. The sentence was copied from a high school biology exam exemplar. The quote is "There is also the effect that in the case of the saviour child, that the child may not feel as loved because it was brought into the world only to help someone else".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive comparatives:

**The sun looks brighter. The crowd felt more friendly. The orange tastes as sweet as ever**.

Negative comparatives:

**The sun looks less bright.  The crowd felt less friendly. The orange tastes suddenly not as sweet**